# Google Calendar API / Python : I can't delete event

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

when I want to delete an event with a "XXXXXXX@group.calendar.google.com" with this command (below), it's work with my primary email but not with this "XXXXXXX@group.calendar.google.com":

```
 from __future__ import print_function import httplib2 import os
 
 from apiclient import discovery from oauth2client import file  import
 oauth2client from oauth2client import client from oauth2client import
 tools
 
 import datetime import requests
 
 SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar' CLIENT_SECRET_FILE
 = 'credentials.json' APPLICATION_NAME = 'Google Calendar API Python Quickstart' calendar_use = 'XXXXXXX@group.calendar.google.com'
 
 def get_credentials():
     """Gets valid user credentials from storage.
 
     If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
     the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.
 
     Returns:
         Credentials, the obtained credential.
     """
     home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
     credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
     if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
         os.makedirs(credential_dir)
     credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,'calendar-python-quickstart.json')
 
     store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
     credentials = store.get()
     if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
         flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
         flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
         if flags:
             credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
         else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
             credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
         print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
     return credentials
 
 def deleteEvent():
     get_credentials()
     credentials = get_credentials()
     http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
     service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)
     x = requests.delete('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/xxxxxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com/events/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
     print(x.text)
 
 deleteEvent()
```

But i get this error message, and i can't find the answer.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "calendar-json.googleapis.com",
          "method": "calendar.v3.Events.Delete"
```

When I open the link, which is write in the error code, I don't find the anwser
However, I can already create event, but i can't delete. Thanks for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you don't need to use `request.delete` (Because the request doesn't get auth credentials) but something like

```
service.events().delete(calendarId=calendarId, eventId=eventId).execute()
```

you just need to set up proper `calendarId`, `eventId`

Comment: I already do it but i got a "NameError: name 'service' is not defined"

Comment: but you definitely define it here `service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)`.

where do you put that line with `service.events().delete...`?

Comment: I tried out of the function but it shows the error

Comment: If it is out of the function, the `service` out of scope. You need to replace your `requests.delete` with this `service.events()` call